# I don't know how to prove $f(x)\leq 1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Tags: inequality

Given $f(x)=1+(-4x+4x^2)c$, for all $0\leq c\leq 1$. How to prove $f(x)\leq 1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$?

I have tried to plot the function for $c=0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75,\text{ and } 1$ , and it holds.
[image]

But now I don't have idea to prove it. I have spend many time to think it. Anyone know the hint to prove it?

Comment: One way is to check the monotonicity of the function, and then use the value of $f$ at suitable points to put bounds on the function.

Comment: $(-4x+4x^2)=-4x(1-x)\leq 0$ when $0\leq x\leq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $0\le c\le1$. Then $$f_c(x)=1+(-4x+4x^2)c\le1\iff(-4x+4x^2)c\le0\iff(-4x+4x^2)\le0\iff4x^2\le4x\iff x^2\le x$$, which is true if $0\le x\le 1$